# How do I make append() and appendChild() make the elements I want?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a gallery with a filter that has six images on it, the gallery is inside an `ul` and every `li` element have one of the two clases that make the filter work. This is the structure:

```
<div id="productsGrid">
   <ul id="portfolio">
      <li class="men">
         <img src="images/grid-images/men/1.jpg" /><div class="caption">TEXT IMG 1</div>
      </li>
      <li class="woman">
         <img src="images/grid-images/woman/1.jpg" /><div class="caption">TEXT IMG 2</div>
      </li>
      <li class="men">
         <img src="images/grid-images/men/2.jpg" /><div class="caption">TEXT IMG 3</div>
      </li>
      <li class="woman">
         <img src="images/grid-images/woman/2.jpg" /><div class="caption">TEXT IMG 4</div>
      </li> 
      <li class="men">
         <img src="images/grid-images/men/3.jpg" /><div class="caption">TEXT IMG 5</div>
      </li>
      <li class="woman">
         <img src="images/grid-images/woman/3.jpg" /><div class="caption">TEXT IMG 6</div>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have stored in the website files a total of 12 images between the two different clases, for efficiency reasons and design I don't want the 12 images to be loaded inside the structure so that's why I call the first three of each one. What I'm trying to achieve with the script of the click function of the filter is that the rest of the three images of every class are built with the `append()` and `appendChild()` function.

```
  $('#filter li').click(function() {
        $('#filter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');
        var i = 4;
        if(filterVal == 'all') {
          $('#portfolio li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        }else {
          $('#portfolio li').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
               $(this).remove();
               var linew = document.createElement("li");
               linew.className = filterVal;
               imgNew = document.createElement("img");
               imgNew.src = 'images/grid-images/'+filterVal+'/'+i+'.jpg'
               $('#portfolio').appendChild(linew);
               linew.appendChild(imgNew);
            } else {

            }
          });
        }
        return false;
      });
```

This code runs and the console doesn't give any error message but the elements that are created with the `document.createElement` are not shown. I want that every time one of the filter buttons is clicked deletes the three images that don't have the clicked class and the other three of that class are shown. The filter bar just has three options that should display the six images of the class that was clicked.

```
<div id="topBar">
  <ul id="filter">
    <li class="current"><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Woman</a></li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

I don't know if this code is done properly or there is another way of making this easier but im not that expert in JS and jQuery yet. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: why are you mixing vanilla js with jquery ?

Comment: yes: appendChild is a dom method and append is a jquery method. In other words, you should be using append, not appendChild here.

Comment: where? as far as I know im just using js and jquery

Comment: oh ok, i see...

Comment: @R.Garcia appendChild is a pure js function it will not work for a jquery object

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
           var $linew = $("<li />");
           $linew.attr("class", filterVal);
           $imgNew = $("<img />");
           $imgNew.attr("src", 'images/grid-images/'+filterVal+'/'+i+'.jpg');
           $linew.append($imgNew);
           $('#portfolio').append($linew);
```

Note that you could use the image as a background image for the classes .man and .woman, that would simplify your js code.

Comment: i try both codes, they are working well i still have problems to solve because if i keep clicking in the man or woman class the first 3 images disappear. and the thing is that i need a diferent image for every li element in the structure. by now the append is working fine.

Comment: Yes, why are You removing and inserting lines? why not simply fade them out and add class .hidden?

Comment: is because i need that the rest of the image that are not in the struture of the gallery  appair when the men or woman class are clicked. in the begining there are just 3 of woman and just 3 of man. When the user click in the man for example the images of woman should be replace with the mans class images

Answer (score 0):

Try the jquery way:

```
 if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
    $(this).remove();
    var linew = '<li class="'+filterVal+'"><img src="images/grid-images/'+filterVal+'/'+i+'.jpg"/></li>'
    $('#portfolio').append(linew);
 } else {
 }
```